# My core.clj functions will not upload into the REPL. I've checked them all individually and they all compile by hand. What do I do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, vscode-calva

I'm coding a small project and so far all of my code is just in the core.clj file.  I can't remember the exact steps I took, but I was messing around with the debugger and now my core.clj file will not compile at all.  I've gone through all of my functions and they all compile fine by hand.  There are no syntax errors. I've removed the #dbg tags from any offending functions just in case but that still doesn't work.  What do I do from here?  I'm new to coding so I'm lost right now.  Currently I'm using VSCode with Calva plugin.  I fear I unknowingly pressed a key combination that mixed up some code but that should have shown up during the hand-compile process.

Comment: If you're using Leiningen, there is a helpful command `lein check` which will recompile things from scratch in a clean context. Often surfaces errors that have snuck in to source files while REPLing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  For some reason a function was changed and it wasn't compiling.  Thank you